# when are objects and data types deleted in c++

Tags: c++, scope, delete-operator

I want to get a complete grasp when objects and data types are deleted including all exceptions and concerns I should be aware of. Here is what I understand so far. please correct any of this and add conditions/situations I missed.

If I create an object or data type on the stack it is **always** delete when I leave the scope in which it was created.

If I create an object or data type on the heap it is delete **only** when I call delete on it.

When an object or data type is returned from a function it is copied and the copy is passed out of the function call unless I do this:

```
return &ans;
```

where ans is my object I'm returning in which case the object or data type itself is returned.

Passing parameters into functions uses & similarly to avoid copying the parameters.

Assuming my understanding is so far correct, would the copying of the data type or object use a copy constructor I defined?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You cannot "create types" as part of the program execution. Types make up a program, but they're not things that a program manipulates.

Comment: As of C++17, copies are only created when a function returns a prvalue *and* the prvalue is eventually materialized.

Comment: The third point is not correct. There can be return type optimization in c++11 such that even it is return by value, the value is not going to be copied but moved.

Comment: What I mean by types is instances of a type such as an int, double, char etc. I'll change the wording if someone can tell me the correct term for this

Comment: @fred Those are called objects.

Comment: @ Zhuoran He, could you explain when that would happen

Comment: @melpomene, so instances of a class and instances of a type are both called objects?

Comment: @fred Does the "stack" in your description include both automatic storage and register storage?

Comment: A class is a type, so yes, instances are commonly referred to as objects.

Comment: Copies of objects may be avoided by using references and pointers.  In these cases, the object isn't copied, but the object can be manipulated directly.

Comment: @melpomene, I'm not familiar with automatic storage and register storage

Comment: @fred According to the standard, "An *object* is a region of storage."

Comment: User defined types may be deleted by the compiler after the compiler has processed the translation unit.  See also *precompiled headers*.

Comment: Note: construct/destruct versus allocation new/delete

Comment: @fred, there are objects which may not be placed on stack or heap.  Examples:  global variables, and static variables inside functions.  Variables are deleted based on their *assigned lifetime or scope*.

Comment: I am still unclear if my third point is correct or not, how exactly does the returning of objects work. are they copied or not. when are they copied, how do i know if it will be copied or just moved etc.

Comment: @thomasMatthews, where are static variables stored then?

Comment: When you do `return &x`, you return a pointer to `x` (by copy). The lifetime of `x` is not affected. If `x` is a local variable, you get a dangling (invalid) pointer.

Comment: Objects on the stack are **never** deleted. They are **destroyed** when they go out of scope.

Comment: how do I avoid copying what I return then without having a dangling pointer?

Comment: @Fred: *static* variables are stored in a separately named section of memory.  As to where that memory is, is a compiler dependent issue.  Some compilers may group global variables and static variables into the same memory area, which is determined at compilation or linking phase.

Comment: @pete Becker, whats the difference between destroyed and deleted

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, they must have a scope though so that they are deleted when they leave it. for  example if i create a static object in a function and leave the function is the instance deleted or not?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the help, I have to go now so if someone could summarize this and add everything missed into an answer that would be great

Comment: `delete` only goes with `new`. It destroys the object and releases the memory that was allocated for it on the free store.